# What data type should my models property use when creating an EditorFor for <input type="week"/>?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

So I want to pass the  week through the HTML through my model like this:

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Week,
new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", @type="week"} })
```

and I'm wondering what datatype in C# if any accepts this type, datetime returns nothing.

Comment: There is no "week" data type in C#? Your question is not clear

Comment: Looking at the HTML ref it says week is represented as a string, Id try that for starters https://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/input.week.html

Comment: So your question is what data type to use when binding to an input type="week" control using Razor?

Comment: datatype is `string`

Comment: @bUKaneer if you could put your comment as an answer to my question I'll mark it as the answer, thanks for the help guys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the HTML spec the input type="week" is a string so just define the model property as string and you should be good to go!

More info here: https://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/input.week.html